# How to implement google map API key in Android sent from backend API response

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, backend

Currently, I am working on a project where the map API key response sent by the backend API. I have to use that key in my Android project for map service. The project uses the map heavily so, how can I effectively use the google map API key responded from my backend API call.

> The language I'm using here is `kotlin` and the response for the map
>   key will look like:

```
{ 
   "api_key":"<my_google_map_api_key"
}
```

Any solution to this answer will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hehe. I think it's impossible because in this case, google can't get money from google maps cuz everyone just start to generate and replacing map api_keys:D The only reason you(your customer) could want to do this is to avoid paying for google map when traffic because bigger than free plan.

Answer (score 1):

If your layout contain MapView then it is possible .
ex:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
super.onCreate(arg0);
String mapApiKey = <your choice logic here>
mMapView = new MapView(this, mapApiKey);
setContentView(mMapView);
```